# Groups in group on routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Simple little question :
on Laravel 4, it seems that a group of routes into an another group isn't working.
Is there any solution to make it work ? Or do I have to write my routes in another way ?

Example :

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'app', 'before' => 'auth_api'), function()
{
    Route::group(array('prefix' => '{app_id}'), function()
    {
        Route::get('/', 'AppController@show');

        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'achievement'), function()
        {
            Route::get('/{id}', 'AchievementController@show');
        });
    });
});
```

I'm unable to get a route to (example here) `app/1234/achievement/1`
Maybe it's too complex here. I have not any error, just a blank page (no PHP error)

Comment: I can use nested groups just fine with my routes. Would you mind posting your `routes.php` file?

Comment: Nested groups do work, but you're using a placeholder (`{app_id}`) inside the groups prefix, this doesn't work. As mentioned in the correct answer you can use my Enhanced Router package that does this. Note that this functionality will *probably* be available by default in Laravel 4.1.

Comment: Thanks Jason, your package rocks for my project !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel 4 isn't offering this possibility but this package : https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router do the work.

Comment: Mh, this package do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using nested groups for filtering, and I can confirm I can use this feature niceliy in Laravel 4.1 without a 3rd party package such as enhanched router.

Comment: True, Laravel 4.1 supports natively nested route prefixing

Comment: Nested routing in L4 is not working for me. Can you point to an example or documentation?

Comment: Same problem here - I have Route::group inside of the Route::group - to group items that require authentication for 'admin' and leave controllers such as login out of it. Any idea?

Comment: By the look at this ticket http://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-nested-route-groups - it looks like you have to specify the 'prefix' for each group, which won't work for what I need - as I want the prefix to be the same as the main group- just add filter.

Comment: I'm having a bad issue for this. nested Group works but smth doesnt work(404)